# how to make array while looping another array in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
     name = name.push(input.files[i].name)
}
```

I want to get the name of the files and put them in a array so I can post them to a php file to upload. Please help.

The variable name is the array I want to post.

is there a loop in javascript like foreach in php

Comment: so what's the problem in this?

Comment: What is the question / problem you are having?

Comment: i want to upload files using jquery and php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
var name = [];
for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
     name.push(input.files[i].name);
}
```

Comment: it doesn't give an array after the loop

Comment: name is your array - you add the values inside name and later you can iterate over it.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way

```
var name = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
   name[i] = name.push(input.files[i].name)
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `name[i] = inputfiles[i].name;`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer the code uses both for loop and jquery $.each loop
Thanx

```
for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
   $.each(input.files.name,function(index,value){
     if(index == 'name'){
       name.push(value)
     }
   })
}
```